# Setting a trap for INT doesn't work in a subshell

Tags: shell, subshell, trap, interrupt

```
$ bash -c "trap \"echo INT\" INT; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait
[1] 27811
INT
[1]+  Done                    bash -c "trap \"echo INT\" INT; sleep 3"

$ (bash -c "trap \"echo INT\" INT; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT $pid; wait)
```

Can you explain why the `SIGINT` handler doesn't get invoked in the second case?

Comment: @zevzek That doesn't explain why `bash -c "trap...` works. Anyways, I've found that, "When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands [ignore SIGINT](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html)..." But they don't say, when it's not in effect.

Comment: @zevzek Okay, if I take your wording, and if `cmd` in `(cmd)` is a script, than it explains things. The quote from the docs seems like it should explain things, but it doesn't. See the updated answer. On a side note, you can check out [my solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676839/29867) to the X problem if you feel like it.

Comment: @zevzek Well, I looked at `$-`. Surprisingly here `-m` is set, but job control is supposedly disabled: `(echo $-; sleep 1 & fg)`. Anyway, I seem to have answered my question, particularly with your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Job control refers to the protocol for allowing a user to move between multiple process groups (or jobs) within a single login session.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html

Generally it's enabled in interactive shells, and disabled in non-interactive ones:

```
$ echo $-; sleep 1 & fg
himBHs
[1] 84366
sleep 1

$ bash -c 'echo $-; sleep 1 & fg'
hBc
bash: line 1: fg: no job control
```

In this case... apparently job control is disabled, and `$-` can't be relied upon:

```
$ (echo $-; sleep 1 & fg)
himBHs
bash: fg: no job control
```

> The shell associates a job with each pipeline.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html

That is, when job control is enabled each pipeline is executed in a separate process group.

`pgid.sh`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ps -o pgid= $$
```

```
$ ./pgid.sh >&2 | ./pgid.sh >&2; ./pgid.sh; ./pgid.sh & wait
  93439
  93439
  93443
[1] 93445
  93445
[1]+  Done                    ./a.sh

$ (./pgid.sh >&2 | ./pgid.sh >&2; ./pgid.sh; ./pgid.sh & wait)
  93749
  93749
  93749
  93749
```

One of the jobs is a foreground job, the rest are background ones.

Background jobs are [not supposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106725/why-do-shells-ignore-sigint-and-sigquit-in-backgrounded-processes/45106961#45106961) to be tied to the shell that started them. If you exit a shell, they will continue running. As such they shouldn't be interrupted by `SIGINT`, not by default. When job control is enabled, that is fulfilled automatically, since background jobs are running in separate process groups. When job control is disabled, `bash` makes the asynchronous commands ignore `SIGINT`, and doesn't let them (if they're `bash` scripts) override it.

That is, here:

```
$ bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT "$pid"; wait
```

the background job (`bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; sleep 3"`) is executed by an interactive shell, which has job control enabled. As a result the background job receives `SIGINT`.

When we wrap it into a non-interactive shell without job control:

```
$ (bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT "$pid"; wait)
```

`bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; sleep 3"` ignores `SIGINT`, and `trap ... INT` is also ignored.

This can be confirmed this way:

```
$ bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; trap; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT "$pid"; wait
[1] 293631
trap -- 'echo INT' SIGINT
trap -- '' SIGFPE
INT
[1]+  Done                    bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; trap; sleep 3"

$ (bash -c "trap 'echo INT' INT; trap; sleep 3" & pid=$!; sleep 1; kill -INT "$pid"; wait)
trap -- '' SIGINT
trap -- '' SIGQUIT
trap -- '' SIGFPE

$ bash -c 'ps -o pid,ignored,comm,args -p $$' & wait
[1] 345833
    PID          IGNORED COMMAND         COMMAND
 345833 0000000000000000 ps              ps -o pid,ignored,comm,args -p 345833
[1]+  Done                    bash -c 'ps -o pid,ignored,comm,args -p $$'

$ (bash -c 'ps -o pid,ignored,comm,args -p $$' & wait)
    PID          IGNORED COMMAND         COMMAND
 345629 0000000000000006 ps              ps -o pid,ignored,comm,args -p 345629
```

A couple of relevant quotes:

> Non-builtin commands started by Bash have signal handlers set to the values inherited by the shell from its parent. **When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands ignore `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`** in addition to these inherited handlers. Commands run as a result of command substitution ignore the keyboard-generated job control signals `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, and `SIGTSTP`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html

> **Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.**

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap

> Job control refers to the ability to selectively stop (suspend) the execution of processes and continue (resume) their execution at a later point. A user typically employs this facility via an interactive interface supplied jointly by the operating system kernel’s terminal driver and Bash.
>
> The shell associates a job with each pipeline. It keeps a table of currently executing jobs, which may be listed with the `jobs` command. When Bash starts a job asynchronously, it prints a line that looks like:
>
> ```
> [1] 25647
> ```
>
> indicating that this job is job number `1` and that the process ID of the last process in the pipeline associated with this job is `25647`. All of the processes in a single pipeline are members of the same job. Bash uses the job abstraction as the basis for job control.
>
> To facilitate the implementation of the user interface to job control, the operating system maintains the notion of a current terminal process group ID. Members of this process group (processes whose process group ID is equal to the current terminal process group ID) receive keyboard-generated signals such as `SIGINT`. These processes are said to be in the foreground. **Background processes are those whose process group ID differs from the terminal’s; such processes are immune to keyboard-generated signals.** Only foreground processes are allowed to read from or, if the user so specifies with `stty tostop`, write to the terminal. Background processes which attempt to read from (write to when `stty tostop` is in effect) the terminal are sent a `SIGTTIN` (`SIGTTOU`) signal by the kernel’s terminal driver, which, unless caught, suspends the process.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html